# Constructing Binary Tree from Inorder and Postorder Traversal

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to construct a binary tree from postorder and inorder traversal. I believe the recursion part is correct however I'm not sure about the base cases. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I have tried different combination of base cases but I can't seem to get it working.

```py
class BinaryTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def binary_tree_from_postorder_inorder(postorder, inorder):
    node_to_inorder_idx = {data: i for i, data in enumerate(inorder)}


    def helper(
        postorder_start, postorder_end, inorder_start, inorder_end
    ):
        if postorder_end >= postorder_start or inorder_end <= inorder_start:
            return None


        root_inorder_idx = node_to_inorder_idx[postorder[postorder_start]]
        left_subtree_size = root_inorder_idx - inorder_start

        root = BinaryTreeNode(postorder[postorder_start])

        root.right = helper(
            postorder_start - 1,
            postorder_start - 1 - left_subtree_size,
            root_inorder_idx + 1,
            inorder_end,
        )
        root.left = helper(
            postorder_start - 1 - left_subtree_size,
            postorder_end,
            inorder_start,
            root_inorder_idx,
        )

        return root

     return helper(len(postorder) - 1, -1, 0, len(inorder))

def inorder(tree):
    stack = []
    results = []

    while stack or tree:
        if tree:
            stack.append(tree)
            tree = tree.left
        else:
            tree = stack.pop()
            results.append(tree.data)
            tree = tree.right
    return results


inorder = ["F", "B", "A", "E", "H", "C", "D", "I", "G"]
postorder = ["F", "A", "E", "B", "I", "G", "D", "C", "H"]

root_pos_in = binary_tree_from_postorder_inorder(postorder, inorder)

print(inorder(root_pos_in))
```

Inputs:

```py
inorder = ["F", "B", "A", "E", "H", "C", "D", "I", "G"]
postorder = ["F", "A", "E", "B", "I", "G", "D", "C", "H"]
```

Actual output using inorder traversal:
`["A", "B", "E", "H", "C"]`

Expected output:
`["F", "B", "A", "E", "H", "C", "D", "I", "G"]`

Comment: Please add language tag and post [mre]

Comment: @c0der I just edited my question and added my complete program. Thank you!

Comment: `root_left = helper....` call is incomplete. Please fix.

Comment: What is that expected output format?  I thought you wanted a tree.

Comment: Sorry for missing it again. I didn't copy it properly. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling for a little longer, I was able to fix the problem. See my updated function below:

```py
def binary_tree_from_postorder_inorder(postorder, inorder):
    if not inorder or not postorder or len(postorder) != len(inorder):
        return None

    node_to_inorder_idx = {data: i for i, data in enumerate(inorder)}

    def helper(postorder_start, postorder_end, inorder_start, inorder_end):
        if postorder_start > postorder_end or inorder_start > inorder_end:
            return None

        root_index = node_to_inorder_idx[postorder[postorder_end]]
        left_subtree_size = root_index - inorder_start

        return BinaryTreeNode(
            postorder[postorder_end],
            helper(
                postorder_start,
                postorder_start + left_subtree_size - 1,
                inorder_start,
                root_index - 1,
            ),
            helper(
                postorder_start + left_subtree_size,
                postorder_end - 1,
                root_index + 1,
                inorder_end,
            ),
        )

    return helper(0, len(postorder) - 1, 0, len(inorder) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I dealt with Python, but that looks like a lot of code for what seems a simple algorithm.

Here is a an example of the application of the algorithm:

We start with

```
postorder  |  inorder
-----------|----------
           |               
FAEBIGDCH  | FBAEHCDIG
        ^  |
        |  |
         `-+-------------- last value of postorder: 'H': this is the root value
           |               
FAEBIGDCH  | FBAEHCDIG
           |     ^
           |     |
           |      `------- index of 'H' in inorder: 4
           |               
FAEB_....  | FBAE_....
  ^        |   ^
  |        |   |
  |        |    `--------- everything before index 4
  |        |
   `-------+-------------- everything before index 4
           |               
....IGDC_  | ...._CDIG
      ^    |        ^ 
      |    |        |
      |    |         `---- everything beginning with index 5 (4 + 1)
      |    |
       `---+-------------- everything between index 4 and the 'H' at the end
           |               
FAEB       | FBAE
  ^        |   ^
  |        |   |
   `-------+---+---------- recur on these if not empty: this is the left child
           |               
     IGDC  |      CDIG
       ^   |        ^
       |   |        |
        `--+--------+----- recur on these if not empty: this is the right child
```

This will quickly lead us to a tree like

```
               H
               |
      +--------+--------+
      |                 |
      B                 C
      |                 |
+-----+-----+           +-----+
|           |                 |
F           E                 D
            |                 |
        +---+                 +---+
        |                         |
        A                         G
                                +-+
                                |
                                I
```

So while I can't really critique your Python, I can offer a pretty simple JS version:

```js
const makeTree = (
    postord, inord, 
    len = postord.length, val = postord[len - 1], idx = inord.indexOf(val)
  ) =>
    len == 1
      ? {val}
    : {
        val,
        ...(idx > 0 ? {left: makeTree(postord.slice(0, idx), inord.slice(0, idx))} : {}),
        ...(idx < len - 1 ? {right: makeTree(postord.slice(idx, len - 1), inord.slice(idx + 1, len))} : {})
      }

const postOrder = ["F", "A", "E", "B", "I", "G", "D", "C", "H"]
const inOrder =   ["F", "B", "A", "E", "H", "C", "D", "I", "G"]

console .log (
  makeTree (postOrder, inOrder)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write your thorough response. I was able to implement it after fiddling with it for a little more, the change I made was to use postorder_end index for determining the root, not use reverse indices for postorder_start and postorder_end and remove off by one end index. I also was able to use `reduce` to achieve the same.

Comment: I also love the way you have visualized it all.

Comment: @Mahdi: It's considered absolutely appropriate to post an answer to your own question.  If you have a solution you're happy with, add an answer so others can learn from what you've done.